# Synchronise users from PeopleSoft HRMS to an external application

Tags: peoplesoft

I have an enterprise application which needs to synchronise user information from the centralised source. We have been so far been integrating using LDAP with AD using a daemon process.

However, In our next deployment we need to integrate with PeopleSoft HRMS (9.1). The application needs to periodically synchronise users with the PeopleSoft HRMS.

I wanted to check how to proceed on implementing this?

Is there a standard module which would expose these details or does it allow LDAP communication?

Any direction on how to consume user records will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webservices can be implemented with Integration Broker: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tibr/concept_IntroductiontoPeopleSoftIntegrationBroker-076593.html

A more low-level approach could be done with an Application Engine.
Your enterprise application could generate an XML/csv.
You would make a record in peopletools that corresponds with the fields in the XML/csv file. Then you make a fileLayout. If you drag this fileLayout into the Application Engine peoplecode window, you get a template of what your code should be and you'd have to complete it with some paths to files and minimal logic to process and import the data into your user tables.
Remember you can schedule Application Engines with reccurence, so after setting this up all you need to worry about is that the file gets updated.

If you require validation you should also look into feeding the data to a Component Interface after reading it in via Application Engine.